# Why am I getting 400 Bad Requests with these proxy servers?

Tags: python, proxy, ip, web-crawler, scrapy

So I'm pretty new to networking and the use of proxy servers. I have a scraper that scrapes certain websites, but I realize that I need to alter my IP addresses and whatnot so that I don't get booted from the website. I found the following program on GitHub that I want to use:

https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies

I have everything implemented as follows:

Spider:

```
# This package will contain the spiders of your Scrapy project
#
# Please refer to the documentation for information on how to create and manage
# your spiders.
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from backpage_scrape import items
#from toolz import first
#import ipdb
#from lxml import html
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os

HOME = os.environ['HOMEPATH']
os.chdir(HOME +       "/Desktop/GitHub/Rover/backpage_scrape/backpage_scrape/spiders/") 

# Method that gets today's date
def backpage_date_today():
    now = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=4)
    weekdays = ['Mon. ','Tue. ','Wed. ','Thu. ','Fri. ','Sat. ','Sun. ']
    months = ['Jan. ','Feb. ','Mar. ','Apr. ','May. ', 'Jun. ','Jul. ','Aug. ','Sep. ','Oct. ','Nov. ','Dec. ']
    backpage_date = weekdays[now.weekday()] + months[now.month-1] + str(now.day)
    return backpage_date

# Method that gets yesterday's date
def backpage_date_yesterday():
    now = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=1, hours=4)
    weekdays = ['Mon. ','Tue. ','Wed. ','Thu. ','Fri. ','Sat. ','Sun. ']
months = ['Jan. ','Feb. ','Mar. ','Apr. ','May. ', 'Jun. ','Jul. ','Aug. ','Sep. ','Oct. ','Nov. ','Dec. ']
backpage_date = weekdays[now.weekday()] + months[now.month-1] + str(now.day)
return backpage_date

# Open file which contains input urls
with open("test_urls.txt","rU") as infile:
    urls = [row.strip("\n") for row in infile]

class BackpageSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'backpage'
allowed_domains = ['backpage.com']
start_urls = urls

def parse(self,response):

    if response.status < 600:

        todays_links = []

        backpage_date = backpage_date_today()
        yesterday_date = backpage_date_yesterday()

        if backpage_date in response.body:
            # Get all URLs to iterate through
            todays_links = response.xpath("//div[@class='date'][1]/following-sibling::div[@class='date'][1]/preceding-sibling::div[preceding-sibling::div[@class='date']][contains(@class, 'cat')]/a/@href").extract()

        # timeOut = 0
        for url in todays_links: 
            # Iterate through pages and scrape
            # if timeOut == 10:
            #   time.sleep(600)
            #   timeOut = 0
            # else:
            #   timeOut += 1

            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_ad_into_content)

        for url in set(response.xpath('//a[@class="pagination next"]/@href').extract()):
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse)

    else:
        time.sleep(600)
        yield scrapy.Request(response.url,callback=self.parse)

# Parse page
def parse_ad_into_content(self,response):
    item = items.BackpageScrapeItem(url=response.url,
        backpage_id=response.url.split('.')[0].split('/')[2].encode('utf-8'),
        text = response.body,
        posting_body= response.xpath("//div[@class='postingBody']").extract()[0].encode('utf-8'),
        date = datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(hours=5),
        posted_date = response.xpath("//div[@class='adInfo']/text()").extract()[0].encode('utf-8'),
        posted_age = response.xpath("//p[@class='metaInfoDisplay']/text()").extract()[0].encode('utf-8'),
        posted_title = response.xpath("//div[@id='postingTitle']//h1/text()").extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
        )
    return item
```

Portion of settings.py:

```
# Retry many times since proxies often fail
RETRY_TIMES = 10
# Retry on most error codes since proxies fail for different reasons
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    # Fix path to this module
    'backpage_scrape.randomproxy.RandomProxy': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}

PROXY_LIST = 'C:/Users/LPrice/Desktop/GitHub/Rover/backpage_scrape/backpage_scrape/proxies.txt'
```

randomproxy.py is the exact same as it is on the GitHub link.

Proxies.txt:

```
https://6.hidemyass.com/ip-4
https://5.hidemyass.com/ip-1
https://4.hidemyass.com/ip-1
https://4.hidemyass.com/ip-2
https://4.hidemyass.com/ip-3
https://3.hidemyass.com/ip-1
https://3.hidemyass.com/ip-2
https://3.hidemyass.com/ip-3
https://2.hidemyass.com/ip-1
https://2.hidemyass.com/ip-2
https://2.hidemyass.com/ip-3
https://1.hidemyass.com/ip-1
https://1.hidemyass.com/ip-2
https://1.hidemyass.com/ip-3
https://1.hidemyass.com/ip-4
https://1.hidemyass.com/ip-5
https://1.hidemyass.com/ip-6
https://1.hidemyass.com/ip-7
https://1.hidemyass.com/ip-8
```

So if you look at the top of the GitHub README, you'll see that it says to "copy-paste into text file and reformat to http://host:port format." I'm not sure how I do that, or if already is in that format.

Like I said, my errors are 400 Bad Requests. I'm not sure if it's useful, but the console is saying:

```
Retrying <GET http://sf.backpage.com/restOfURL> <failed 10 times>: 400 Bad Request
```

Is it supposed to be showing the proxies in the URL above, before the "sf.backpage.com" portion?

Thanks a ton for your time...I really appreciate the help.

EDIT: Also, I wasn't sure where/how to insert the snippet of code at the bottom of the GitHub's README. Any suggestions on that would also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLs in your proxies.txt are not really proxies.

Go to http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/ and search proxies for HTTP protocol. You need to take IP address and Port columns from search results and write them to proxies.txt file in http://IP Address:Port format.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much!! However, now I'm getting an error when I return __inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred()). Would this be related to the fact that I didn't implement that small bottom section of the GitHub README?

Comment: Fixed that previous issue, however now the servers are timing out. I wonder if they're just slow servers and if we should pay for more?